# Regex find first 20 characters after an email stored in variable

Tags: c#, regex

```
string subject = null;
string toFind = "["+emailFound+"]([.20])";

        Match match = Regex.Match(messageText, toFind, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


            if (match.Success)
            {
                subject = match.Value;

        }    
    MessageBox.Show(subject);
```

This is code I have so far, I'm really new at regex and not quite sure how it works. How would I get the first 20 characters after "emailFound"

Thanks

Comment: `[.20]` means "match any one of these characters `.`, `2` or `0`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No more errors, but now it's just not finding anything after the emailFound...

That's because you need to get the [`Group`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value after you check the match instance.

```
string toFind = Regex.Escape(emailFound) + "(?s)(.{20})";

Match match   = Regex.Match(messageText, toFind);

if (match.Success) {
  subject = match.Groups[1].Value; // Get the Group value
}
```

See [`live demo`](http://ideone.com/NpLMGV)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
string toFind = Regex.Escape(emailFound)+"(?s)(.{20})";
```

`(?s)` allows the dot to match newlines (you can remove it and add the `RegexOptions.SingleLine` in the `Match` method.)

`.{20}` twenty characters

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid, I'm getting "parsing "\Qanyemail@gmail.com\E(?s)(.{.20})" - Unrecognized escape sequence \E

Comment: @ÁppleAssassin11: Sorry, the `\Q...\E` feature doesn't exist in .net. You must use `Regex.Escape` instead. :)

Comment: No more errors, but now it's just now finding anything after the emailFound...Very frustrating

Comment: @ÁppleAssassin11: And what do you want to find?